# Deal, compromise, get along vs reconcile

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, verbs

Based on [this definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compromise) compromise can be used for reduction of your demands or changing your opinion in order to reach an agreement with ***someone*** (not something). Is it possible to say something like:

> - You have to learn how to compromise with the lack of money.
> - You have to learn how to compromise with this condition / situation. *(here, as far as I know the best choice would be "deal")*

Where the object in my question is not a person but something other that an alive individual?
If not then please let me know if the verbs "[get along](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-along)", "[reconcile](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reconcile)" or "deal" work or not?

This is not a 'yes' or 'no' question. I am looking for the best word for many cases just asking this question and clarifying their usages for myself. I may ask about some more related examples, but whereas in each thread we won;t be able to bring up more than one specific case, then I may make another similar question.

Comment: You *compromise with* someone, you *adjust to* a situation.

Answer (score 2):

I think ***live with*** is what you are looking for. It means *to accept something unpleasant that you cannot change*.

But *live with the lack of money* sounds weird so I'd change it to *live paycheck to paycheck*. Or you can say *live with less/cope with money worries*

You can also check out [these words](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-be-patient-and-to-not-complain-too-much) meaning "to be patient, and to not complain too much." Personally I like these two words - *bear* and *tolerate* - both can be used when you are talking about some unpleasant situations. And here you can check how these words are used in the sentences: the word 'tolerate' in this [article about strong leaders](http://www.forbes.com/sites/lizryan/2016/08/22/ten-things-strong-leaders-wont-tolerate/#2fcb173352b7), 'bear' in this [essay on the old man and the sea](http://jetwriters.com/the-old-man-and-the-sea-essay/) and 'live with' in this [post on dealing with worries](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1955&dat=19560125&id=DgQrAAAAIBAJ&sjid=zJcFAAAAIBAJ&pg=5955,3035925&hl=en).

Comment: Why 'deal' and 'get along' do not work here? Why I'd better change the "lack of money" with less money?

Comment: I'm not saying you should change  "lack of money" to "less money". I'm just saying to me it sounds weird. As to words "deal with" and "get along", I wouldn't use them because "deal with" is used when talking about difficult emotional situations and "get along" when talking about making progress in a particular situation

Comment: Also, "deal with" means to take an action to solve a problem. So, if you want to say not to compromise, not to live with what is happening to you but take some action, you can say "deal with your money problems/issues"

Comment: But since in your examples you used the word "compromise", I thought you were looking for a word which means 'putting up with the situation.' In such case use the words from the list I mentioned earlier

Comment: But why no dictionary refers to emotional situation of the verb "del with"? Like: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deal

Comment: I guess that depends on a dictionary..in [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/deal-with) it's definition #2

Comment: I usually use Macmillan and [Longman dictionary of contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us a little more information or details so that we can think about how we would say whatever it is you are trying to say. 
Maybe "accept" would work. Compromise IS appropriate because it is when you agree but each party does not get all or everything they asked for, so in regards to lack of money, maybe saying "deal with getting less money" because "lack of money" implies there is NONE, but "less money" implies they settled or compromised for less than what they originally wanted or expected. Does that make sense? 
But can you still give us more info so we can give you a better answer?

Comment: You are right @Lisa Ritzheimer. "Lack of sth" implies "no...". But I didn't merely mean "with no money". It is a way of emphasis in our language and I just translated it into English here. :-)